# Issue of replicating a weighted dataset using np.hist

Tags: numpy, histogram, weighted

I have a problem where I'm trying to emulate a weighted data set, and when I use `np.hist` including weights as an input I get a massive discrepancy. Here's the plot of that: [histograms with weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqB7t.png)

Here, the solid blue bins are considered the ground truth, and the orange bins are my attempt at replicating the ground truth. The lines of code used to produce this are:

```
axes.hist(massBound[subhalos], weights=w, bins = 70, range = (1e6,1e10), label = 'Galacticus', fill = True, edgecolor = 'blue')
axes.hist(em_massBound, weights=em_weights, bins = 70, range = (1e6,1e10), label = 'Emulator', fill = False, edgecolor = 'orange')
```

However when I look at the components that go into `.hist` individually everything seems to match. Here's what happens when I execute the same code block as above but deleting the weights input in the `axes.hist` lines:

[histograms without weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql89d.png)

and the distributions of the weights `w` and `em_weights` themselves look identical:

[weights themselves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThTXD.png)

Does anybody know if there's something within `np.hist` that could cause this discrepancy? Thanks!

I tried looking at the inputs of `np.hist` individually to see if there was a discrepancy and there's not. I expected the weighted histograms to look the same if the unweighted histograms and weight distributions look the same.